# Apple iad loaded but not shown, counts towards impressions?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iad

I've noticed something interesting in what seems to be the recommended way to show iads in some apps.

In the [Apple NavigationBanner example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Listings/NavigationBanner_NavigationBanner_AppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198-NavigationBanner_NavigationBanner_AppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_16) ads are downloaded by the AppDelegate but (according to my reading) are only displayed when the user clicks something in the table and a  TextViewController is put on screen.

I'm using this exact behaviour in my app but it occurs to me this could be bad, loading but never showing could cause payouts for ads that were never displayed. I wouldn't want to accidentally fall foul of the rules.

Am I right to be worried about this? Or are Apple perhaps using some unknown mechanism to track what ads have been put on screen instead of simply downloaded to calculate their impression count?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is very careful to ensure that ads are only credited when displayed.

In one of our games, we had an issue with layout which would sometimes cause an object to be in front of the iAd (a very small one, in fact - you could still see the ad).  In those cases, the iAd framework logged that we wouldn't receive an impression because the ad was obscured.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer - sounds like I was worried over nothing!